# postgresql/pg_autoctl ERROR Failed to open file pg_autoctl.state

Tags: postgresql

I have been attempting to install for a few days,

but the following error keeps occurring.

The configuration is as follows.

export PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/16/data

export PGPASSWORD='password'

export  XDG_DATA_HOME=/usr/pgsql-16/xdg

export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/usr/pgsql-16/xdg

export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/usr/pgsql-16/xdg

export PG_REGRESS_SOCK_DIR=/var/run/postgresql

export PG_CONFIG=/usr/pgsql-16/bin/pg_config

export PGPORT=4323

19:41:22 94927 WARN  No encryption is used for network traffic! This allows an attacker on the network to read all replication data.

19:41:22 94927 WARN  Using --ssl-self-signed instead of --no-ssl is recommend to achieve more security with the same ease of deployment.

19:41:22 94927 WARN  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html for details on how to improve

19:41:22 94927 INFO  Using default --ssl-mode "prefer"

19:41:22 94927 INFO  Started pg_autoctl postgres service with pid 94930

19:41:22 94930 INFO   /usr/pgsql-16/bin/pg_autoctl do service postgres --pgdata /var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master -v

19:41:22 94927 INFO  Started pg_autoctl node-init service with pid 94931

19:41:22 94931 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:22 94931 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Restarting service node-init

19:41:23 94934 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:23 94934 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Restarting service node-init

19:41:23 94935 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:23 94935 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Restarting service node-init

19:41:23 94936 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:23 94936 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Restarting service node-init

19:41:23 94937 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:23 94937 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Restarting service node-init

19:41:23 94938 ERROR Failed to open file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state": No such file or directory

19:41:23 94938 ERROR Failed to read Keeper state from file "/var/lib/pgsql/.local/share/pg_autoctl/var/lib/pgsql/16/data/master/pg_autoctl.state"

19:41:23 94927 ERROR pg_autoctl service node-init exited with exit status 12

19:41:23 94927 FATAL pg_autoctl service node-init has already been restarted 5 times in the last 0 seconds, stopping now

19:41:23 94930 INFO  Postgres controller service received signal SIGTERM, terminating

19:41:23 94927 FATAL Something went wrong in sub-process supervision, stopping now. See above for details.

19:41:23 94927 INFO  Stop pg_autoctl

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

The same error occurs even when running **`pg_autoctl run`**,

and it persists after several reinstallations. Any idea what might be the cause?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCaPa.png)

No matter how many times I reinstall, it remains the same.

postgreSql Version: 16

URL: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_auto_failover.git

Comment: The lines marked "ERROR" seem to say quite clearly what the problem is - a missing configuration directory / file. Are you saying that file is in fact there? If so, what permissions does it have?